# Colouring an n times n grid using n colours

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, checkerboard

Inspired by [the four colours puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/44740/5373).

The goal is to color the squares of an $n\times n$ grid with $n$ colors such that

- All squares are coloured.
- no two squares of the same color touch at an edge or corner
- there are an equal number of squares of each color.

For which values of $n$ is this possible?

Comment: @CipherRiddle Michael is right. Your first bullet point should really be changed to "all squares are coloured". It's not that it's *insoluble* with the "at most one" thing, it's just ... a bit strange to say "at most one" when you really mean "zero".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's possible if and only if**

> **$n$ is not $2$ or $3$.**

Proof is as follows.

### $n\leq3$

> It's trivially possible for $n=1$. It's impossible for $n=2$ and $n=3$, because four distinct colours are needed in order to colour any $2\times2$ square in such a way that no two cells of the same colour meet at an edge or vertex.

### $n>3$

> Let the first row of the $n\times n$ block contain one cell of each colour. Let the second row contain the same colours in the same order but cycled round by two places (e.g. ABCDEF -> CDEFAB). Keep on filling in each row in this way until you reach the bottom of the $n\times n$ block.

For example, with $n=7$ we have

> ```
> A B C D E F G
> C D E F G A B
> E F G A B C D
> G A B C D E F
> B C D E F G A
> D E F G A B C
> F G A B C D E
> ```

Comment: It's possible for n=1

Comment: @YowE3K Pedant :-D Edited.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for caving in to my pedanticism (I'm not so pedantic that I care whether "pedanticism" is a real word though)

Comment: @YowE3K Oh, I love p̶e̶d̶a̶n̶t̶i̶c̶i̶s̶m̶ pedantry. I'm a pure mathematician; pathological counterexamples are part of my daily bread ;-)

Comment: I should point out that the middle part of the "m" in your last comment does not appear to be crossed out - is that just my display, or did you accidentally use strike-through on the space instead of the "m"?

Comment: @YowE3K SE doesn't support <strike></strike> in comments, so I used [this generator](http://fsymbols.com/generators/strikethrough/). +1 for EXTRA pedantry.